# 2012r2 Server Mananger not showing all VDI Desktops in Collection

Tags: rds, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, vdi

We are running a 4 node 2012r2 Hyper-V Cluster and using Microsoft's RDS/VDI for serving up Virtual Windows 7 desktops. Right now we have about 90 desktops in 3 collections of 30 desktops each.(I know it's hardware overkill but we expect to ramp this up to 500+ users and then who knows?)

My issue happens from time to time. In Server Manager > Collections (see photo link below) when I click on my VDI collection the total number of Desktops is not the ACTUAL number of desktops in the collection. If I go into Failover Cluster Manager or Hyper-V Manager - all 30 desktops are all there for each collection. Only within server manager, one shows 24 (as in the image below in the red circle), another shows 23 and yet another shows 28.

This has happened several times before, and all the rebooting in the world of every server in the environment never ever gets it to see those VMs again. The only way I can get it to show up correctly is to re-create the collection. This seems extreme for an issue like this. Why can't we tell the VDI service to re-inventory the desktops to find these? Or add them back manually?

My Broken Server Manager Interface :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure this is really an "answer" but as with so many other problems with Microsoft's VDI, often the way to get things working right again is the old "reboot". I ended up rebooting all the servers involved with the VDI environment (Gateway, Web Access, Connection Broker, Etc.). I also rebooted all the desktops and the HOSTS too. This seemed to get everything to jive back up again.

Answer (score 0):

When VMs don't show up do you find they are located on a specific Node in the cluster?

I have a similar issue with a 2 node cluster.  HOST1 and HOST2...  VMs on HOST2 don't show though they are in the collection.  If I Live Migrate the VM from HOST2 to HOST1 they show up.

This is an issue for me as we are using RemoteFX and if the VM does not show in the collection list when users login RDP does not know where to look to get a RD License for RemoteFX.